# does word "itself" important here?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence in a book (IT), but I don't know why it has word *itself*. I feel it's not required. Here is the complete sentence:

> This history is **itself** interesting and also serves the purpose of providing an overview of computer structure and function."

I don't understand what *itself* mean here. What is the difference between

> This history is itself interesting

and

> This history is interesting.

Comment: The word "itself" is not important here. You can ignore it. Sometimes the word "itself" is used *appositionally* for emphasis. See sense (2) here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/itself

Comment: *Verbal flourish*. The same question as *why there are so many words that mean X?* An ambiguity allows an author to convey the mood, to establish the rhyme and the style of the text. But in this particular short case - not much so, just a redundant word.

Comment: why people downvote ??

Comment: Fast Snail: Maybe because of lack of research. If you google "itself", the first link you get explains it's "used to emphasize a particular thing or animal mentioned: *the roots are several inches long, though the plant itself is only a foot tall*". If you're learning English, check out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok thanks for your help.it's okay. minus vote  bit hurt me don't know why.but thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intensive use of the reflexive pronoun (one of those ending in *-self*).  It serves to emphasize the antecedent (here, *history*).  In this case it means that the history is interesting in and of itself or all by itself.  That is, the history is interesting even if you disregard the insight the history gives you about "computer structure and function."